# JAX-RS Jersey client gets 400 response when web method parameters are annotated

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

Here is my web service method:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@POST
@Path("login")
public Response login(@NotNull @Valid Credentials credentials) {
// do login
}
```

And here is the snippet of the client code:

```
WebTarget loginTarget = baseTarget
        .path("base")
        .path("login");

Credentials credentials = new Credentials(username, password);

Response resp = loginOperation
        .request()
        .post(
            Entity.entity(credentials, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
        );
```

When I do post, it doesn't reach the login method. Server returns 400 error with empty body.

When I remove `@NotNull @Valid` annotations from credentials parameter it works.

I noticed that Entity#entity method has an overloaded version which accepts `Annotation[]` as a 3rd parameter. And then I came across [this section](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html) of Jersey documentation. So I went ahead a created annotation factories as suggested in the tutorial:

```
public static class ValidFactory extends AnnotationLiteral<Valid> implements Valid {
    public static ValidFactory get() {
        return new ValidFactory();
    }
}
```

and then changed client code to this:

```
.post(
    Entity.entity(credentials, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE,
        new Annotation[] {
            AuthenticationResource.NotNullFactory.get(), 
            AuthenticationResource.ValidFactory.get()
        }
    )
)
```

which unfortunately resulted in the same error.
Google search didn't yield any results, and I don't have much time to dig in Jersey source code. So, maybe someone who knows the solution would share it, please?

**UPDATE**

Just to add to @peeskillet's response. I use custom ExceptionMapper:

```
@Provider
public class ValidationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
      // customize response
    }

}
```

So, in my case, instead of setting a `ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE` property, I had to register the mapper in the server config:

```
GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI)
        new ResourceConfig() {
            {
                register(ValidationExceptionMapper.class)
            }
        }
);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sound like you just need to [configure Jersey to send error messages](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#bv.ValidationError) using [ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE):

> `public static final String BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE`
>
> A Bean Validation (JSR-349) support customization property. If set to true and Bean Validation support has not been explicitly disabled (see [BV_FEATURE_DISABLE](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#BV_FEATURE_DISABLE)), the validation error information will be sent in the entity of the returned Response.
>
> The default value is false. This means that in case of an error response caused by a Bean Validation error, only a status code is sent in the server Response by default.
>
> The name of the configuration property is "jersey.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server".

In your `ResourceConfig`

```
property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
```

or in your web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>
        jersey.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server
    </param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Thanks! My solution was a bit different (see the update), but you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: How to force jetty to respond any errors in JSON format? `@Produces("application/json")` on resource method does nothing ...